# Can't change size of `symbol` element from external svg with CSS, but other `symbol` in same file works

Tags: html, svg

I'm hoping someone can point out where my bug is with this little problem I have.
I can't resize one `<symbol>` from an external svg  with CSS, but I can another `<symbol>` from the same external svg.

In the CSS I'm changing the `width` and `height`. Which `#pluss` handles fine, whereas `#heart` completely ignores it. It just wants to stay at 24px * 24px regardless of CSS sizing.

I can't tell what I'm doing differently. Headscratchingly confusing!

The external icons-defs.svg file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="pluss" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-labeledby="title">
    <title>Add</title>
    <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="heart" viewbox="0 0 24 24" aria-labeledby="title">
    <title>Favourite</title>
    <path d="M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

And in HTML:

```
<button>
  <svg class="icon-heart" role="presentation">
    <use xlink:href="icons-defs.svg#heart"></use>
  </svg>
  Like
</button>
<button>
  <svg class="icon-pluss" role="presentation">
    <use xlink:href="icons-defs.svg#pluss"></use>
  </svg>
  Add Goal
</button>
```

When having the same svg with symbols inline at top of the HTML document it works fine.

Any pointers would be much appreciated :)

Comment: One symbol has a viewBox, one does not. SVG is case sensitive so viewbox is not a functional attribute. HTML is not case sensitive so it works inline when parsed by a HTML parser.

Comment: I think it's somewhere else, because if I copy this code and set the width and height of `.icon-heart` I can change it no problem.

Comment: Rather than arguing with Robert (check his bio to see why you shouldn't), did you actually try his suggestion?

Comment: @robert-longson Thank you! That was it. I read over it so many times, but I missed the lowercase `b`.

Answer (score 2):

@robert-longson wrote the solution in a comment, so I'm copy-pasting it here.

> One symbol has a viewBox, one does not. SVG is case sensitive so viewbox is not a functional attribute. HTML is not case sensitive so it works inline when parsed by a HTML parser.

So changing `viewbox` to `viewBox` (capital B) fixed my bug.